# change table row style on hover

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, css

I created a table without borders styling and I want it to underline a row on hover. However, I am getting pretty odd behaviour. When I move mouse over from upside down, nothing happens. In opposite direction, all touched rows get underlined and stay that way until I move mouse over in some other direction. I am pretty confused by this. I wanted to stay out of jquery for simplicity, but with jquery I get the same result. Here is the code..

```
<div class="information" >
    <table id="summary" >
    <%
        foreach (KeyValuePair<long, float> pair in sums)
        { %>
            <tr>
                <td class="left" >Automat id: <%= pair.Key%></td>
                <td class="right" ><%= pair.Value%></td>
            </tr>
     <% } %>
    </table>
</div>
```

And the css applied to this div:

```
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:.5em;
}

div.information
{
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:1em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: center;
    color:#C80;
    background-color:#FF9;
    border:1px solid #C80;
}

#summary
{
    width: 715px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.left
{
    text-align: left;
}

.right
{
    text-align: right;
}
```

And the faulty part:

```
#summary tr:hover
{
    border-bottom: dotted 1px gray;
}
```

Anyone sees an error? Another way? And sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old, but it showed up in a Google Search of mine.  Browser support for styling tr is pathetic at best.  Your styles need to be on the tds, like:

```
#summary tr:hover td {
  border-bottom:solid 1px #FF9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using JavaScript **onmouseover** and **onmouseout** events. In this events just apply and un-apply your css class.

Comment: Instead of colour...just create two JS functions, and call them in onmouseover/out events. In the JS cals.....u just say..style = text-decoration:none;

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in chrome. It works well on Firefox, and not at all in IE.
(IE doesn't support `:hover`, `border-spacing`, border for collapsed `<tr>`s, it goes on and on...)

I've found a simple workaround for Chrome, however - simply add a bottom border for all `<tr>`s:

```
#summary tr {
  border-bottom:solid 1px #FF9;
}
```

This will also keep your rows from changing heights and jiggle.

Comment: It seems you are right about the bug. Opera works as described, Firefox doesnt work at all, Chrome a little better, but still wrong and IE is complete disaster.
Unfortunatelly, I wanted the page a little dynamic.. but that work.. except for IE.

Comment: I've tested it with the new bottom border, and it seems to work well on FF and Chrome. Strange it isn't working for you... Maybe you're on betas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there seems to be a bug in the way the :hover pseudoselector is being applied to "tr". Change selector to "#summary td:hover {}". It should work.

Comment: Well, yes, it does, but it doesnt underline the whole row, but just half of it.

Comment: half as in both the halves? - If this is the case, declare padding:0

Comment: If I underline a cell and a row has two cells, the whole row won't be underlined. Only half of it.

Comment: You can also try `#summary tr:hover td`, but then the line is broken (two lines for two cells), and Chrome is still twitchy.

Answer (score 0):

One note to add, that does not seem too widely known, unlike every other browser tested, chrome redraws the ENTIRE table when applying styles on tr:hover.  This may have been fixed in newer versions of chrome

This is VERY critical when you have a large table, chrome lags very badly.

Also, I would highly recommend having a border of the same width set on the TDs before hover, and simply match the BG color, vertical shifts like that are horrible UX.  I tried reducing the padding inside the TDs by 1px to account for the border, but had some weird results (yet another reason to hate tables)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to define Script using JQuery to change row style (you should define your css).
**CSS:**

```
.hovercs {
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #70C9C4;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 $(function () {
        $(document).on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $(this).addClass('hovercs');
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $(this).removeClass('hovercs');
            }
        }, 'tbody tr');
    });
```

```js
$(function () {
            $(document).on({
                mouseenter: function () {
                    $(this).addClass('hovercs');
                },
                mouseleave: function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('hovercs');
                }
            }, 'tbody tr');
        });
```

```css
.hovercs {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #70C9C4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Vipin Yadav</td>
    <td>Frankfrut</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ramesh</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Reetika</td>
    <td>Melbourne</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>



</table>

</body>
</html>
```

```
 $(function () {
        $(document).on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $(this).addClass('hovercs');
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $(this).removeClass('hovercs');
            }
        }, 'tbody tr');
    });
```